# How many connections urllib2 could support

Tags: python, generator, urllib2

I have problem with `urllib2`.
I try to create python generator which create connection using `urllib2.open()` method and then want to scrape response, but in fourth call I have exception.

Code example:

```
class HtmlParser(object):

    def __init__(self, search_text,page_count=1):
        self.GoogleSearch = GoogleSearch(search_text,page_count)
        self.GoogleSearch.search()
        # print self.GoogleSearch

    def parse_page(self, link):
        response = opener.open(link).read()
        page = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
        res_page = self.clenup(page)

    def clenup(self, page):
        unnes_elem = Config.get('unnecessary','elements')
        unnes_attr = Config.get('unnecessary','attributes')
        comments = page.findAll(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment))
        [comment.extract() for comment in comments]
        [s.extract() for s in page('script')]
        [s.extract() for s in page('link')]
        return page

    def start_parsing(self):
        for link in self.GoogleSearch.web_links:
            self.parse_page(link)
```

And start like this:

```
pars = HtmlParser(search_text='hello')
pars.start_parsing()
```

Exception:

```
File "parser.py", line 52, in <module>
  pars.start_parsing()
File "parser.py", line 48, in start_parsing
  self.parse_page(link)
File "parser.py", line 26, in parse_page
  response = opener.open(link)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
  response = self._open(req, data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
  '_open', req)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
  result = func(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1214, in http_open
  return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1187, in do_open
  r = h.getresponse(buffering=True)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1051, in getresponse
  response.begin()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 415, in begin
  version, status, reason = self._read_status()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 379, in _read_status
  raise BadStatusLine(line)
httplib.BadStatusLine: ''
```

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 379, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
httplib.BadStatusLine: ''

Comment: Put the traceback in your question by using the [edit] link.

Comment: I edited it in for you, but you didn't provide the whole traceback.  Please finish the work that I began.

Comment: @zondo I have edited

Comment: How many query accept google server (peer IP)? It's equal to your limit.

Comment: This is not going to work.  Automated scraping of search results is not permitted under Google's [terms of service](https://www.google.com/policies/terms/).  Eventually your program will encounter a CAPTCHA and be unable to proceed.